# Docker build gearman not working

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gearman

When I built Docker, the command inside shell script, 'service gearman-job-server start' does not work. So I had to connect manually its container and execute 'service gearman-job-server start'.

Docker file I used is below. Why isn't this working? Do I have to manually start gearman every time I build?

Any suggestion and advice would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
# Gearman
RUN apt-get -y install php-gearman
RUN apt-get -qq -y install gearman-job-server

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN ln -s usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Replace ```RUN usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh``` with ```ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]```

Comment: @tuan What is the reason for adding parenthesis over the path?

Comment: ```https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint``` An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.